# multiple vertical divs with height relative to width

Tags: css, html

part of my css layout sets div heights relative to widths so that the aspect ratio is the same for all screen sizes. this way i never specifically set the height of a div to a px value - the height is simply an aspect ratio of the width. if you have not come across this technique before, [here is a good explanation](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio).

**onto my specific problem...**

with this in mind i have created the following simple div which is twice as wide as it is high: [(to see it in action please see this fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/wn3v2/)

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css">
.container
{
    position:relative;
    width:50%;/*half the width of the whole page*/
    margin:auto;/*center the whole thing*/
}
.relative_container
{
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.set_height
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:50%;/*aspect ratio 2:1*/
}
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='relative_container'>
                <div class='set_height'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

all good so far. however i then want to add another identical div under the first. as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKRPe/), i cannot get them to display any way other than on top of each other. no doubt the answer lies with clearing the divs [as demonstrated here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) but i can't figure it out.

Comment: `.container`s have only 1 element: an absolutely positioned element. Absolutely positioned elements behave like `display:none` elements from their parent's perspective. Also, `clear`ed elements are influenced only by `float`ed elements, but you have no floats in your example.

Comment: thanks. even if i swap `margin:auto` for `float:left` the problem remains

Comment: You should get rid of `pos:abs` somehow.

Comment: `pos:abs` is mandatory http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio

Comment: Have you checked my linked [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKRPe/13/)? Both of the divs widths are twice the size of their height, regardless of window size.

Comment: yeah its looking like the winner atm. just doing a bit of investigation - i've never seen the aspect ratio done without `position:absolute` before :P

Comment: @mulllhausen any reason against my solution ??

Comment: @mikakun please see the comment under your solution, and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `relative_container` class is absolutely positioned, so it's placing both of the divs at top:0, left:0 with the same width and height (so they're on top of each other). This doesn't make sense for what you're doing.

If you change the positioning to relative, and add `float: left` to your strangely named `relative_container`, you will get your desired behavior, as they will "float" to the leftmost possible place in their parent div.

Also, your "clear" divs aren't doing anything. The clear property tells other divs not to float to the right/left of the given div. If the width of your div is 100% (ie. it fills up the parent), then nothing can float next to it anyway.

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/NKRPe/13/

**EDIT:** [This second example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKRPe/50/) accomplishes the same task without using the dummy div. Note that either `padding-top` or `padding-bottom` can be used.

Comment: oops. the `clear` in the html was not meant to be in my question. i have removed it now. it seems that people are not understanding why i have used `position:absolute` so i will add some explanation in now

Comment: the clear div are useless indeed but to get height relative to a width that is a %age this relative/absolute structure is (to my knowledge - had been looking for such a feature recently and came with same solution) necessary

Comment: hmm...it does seem to work without `position:absolute` in the fiddle :) i shall investigate

Comment: can't remember the reason but there were one for using absolute in my case, but maybe it was a layout thing specific to my problem

Comment: No problem. It is also entirely possible to remove the dummy div by using `padding` instead of `margin`. Check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NKRPe/50/). Note that you can use either `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

add to .container :

```
padding:25% 0 0;
```

Comment: that does indeed work. only thing is that i need to change the padding for each new aspect ratio. i know beggars can't be choosers but it looks like @zpr's solution avoids this extra step. thanks anyhow.